# Want to dissolve adjacent polygons but no common edges

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, dissolve, workflow

I have a bunch of parcel data, I want to join the polygons basing on the same owner name.
Even they are not touched, I want merge them together, such a 100 feet tolerance. The purpose is to show the somebody's properties without too much separated lines.
Like this
I have some programming experience, but just start to try to get the tool by python script, and tried arcgis add_in wizard.
If there is some idea about the script work flow, it will be really helpful!

Answer (score 3):

I would try this as a test, if it gives you a good result, put it into a **[SearchCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000050000000)** (arcpy or arcpy.da) that runs through all owners:

1. **[Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000005000000)** out the parcels for a single owner into a new feature class
2. **[Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Buffer/000800000019000000/)** those polygons by 100 ft (51 ft, or 50.1 ft, may be better)
3. **[Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000)** by owner to merge overlapping buffers (or do the dissolve as part of Buffer)
4. **[Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Buffer/000800000019000000/)** negatively i.e. by -100 ft to bring the buffers back close to their original size and boundaries

Alternatively, if you have an Advanced level license then the **[Aggregate Polygons](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Aggregate_Polygons/00700000000s000000/)** tool (from the Cartography toolset) with its ORTHOGONAL option may be what you need.

Comment: Great idea!
But I don't want the around end point. Is there any solution for it? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you must mean the rounded corners for which I do not currently have a suggestion.  Note that I have just included an alternative in my Answer which should not suffer from rounded corners but requires and Advanced level license.

Comment: Thanks very much, that is what I am just doing now, trying to using the "Aggregate Polygons" tool with my owner name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the dissolve tool in the Datamangement Toolbox/Generalization, try using that. Select the file you want to dissolve and click on 'Environments/XY Resolution and Tolerance'. Set the XY Tolerance to for example 100 feet. Be aware this whole process leads to generalization of your data and you might have to play around with the tolerance value to achieve a result you are happy with.

Comment: I cannot find the 'Environments/XY Resolution and Tolerance' options in the tool dialogue

Comment: If you are in 10.1 and you have found and started the dissolve tool you'll see an Environments... button just next to the Cancel button. This next window will allow you to do various settings, one of which will be XY Resolution and Tolerance.

Answer (score 0):

[ArcMap: Dissolve](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000)

Or you can manually select the parcels and use Editor: Merge. This could be scripted for large files. Dissolve is built for this task, and I believe it comes with every license of ArcMAP.

Comment: But in geometry, they are still separated polygons. I don't want any lines or gaps in it.

Comment: If you try to merge parcels/polygons across space, aren't you creating false data if they become one large block? Are there symbolism tricks you can do to get at what you want to do? such as hiding all non-relevant parcels or not using borders?

Comment: Yes, we ignore the minor false of the data. Cause not all the data I want dissolve, only the specific, so, no borders does not work, I think.